# pandas: I need to slice single column into two column separated by commas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which includes a column with two values in it. That looks like this:

| Co-Ordinates |
| --- |
| 23.821352807207695, 90.40975987926335 |
| 23.812076990866696, 90.43087907325717 |

I want to make extra two columns from this existing column using its values which will be looked like this:

| Co-Ordinates | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23.821352807207695, 90.40975987926335 | 23.821352807207695 | 90.40975987926335 |
| 23.812076990866696, 90.43087907325717 | 23.812076990866696 | 90.43087907325717 |

I have searched for this problem but didn't found any solution. Or maybe I don't know the exact term to search for. I need help to solve this problem with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:
[Str.split()](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-str-split.php)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['23.821352807207695, 90.40975987926335','23.812076990866696, 90.43087907325717'], columns = ['Coordinates'])
df[['Lat','Long']] = df['Coordinates'].str.split(',',expand=True) 
df
```

Output:

```
    Coordinates                             Lat                 Long
0   23.821352807207695, 90.40975987926335   23.821352807207695  90.40975987926335
1   23.812076990866696, 90.43087907325717   23.812076990866696  90.43087907325717
```